# IntelliJ IDEA live template with link

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-templates

How to make [Live Template](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-templates.html) with web link? Just I would to navigate this link on browser  like it possible on Java code [Navigating to Declaration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/navigating-to-declaration-or-type-declaration-of-a-symbol.html).

Example:

[image]

I wrote a little bit but me need your help with a link:

[image]

Comment: What is the desired output and what do you actually get?

Comment: @Vic I want to navigate by link in browser. Like it can do with Java classes: [Navigating to Declaration](http://goo.gl/RiZmV).

Comment: 1. Links in comments are not 'clickable', so, whatever links you enter here, you won't be able to use them for navigation           2. if the live templates are concerned, it's not clear for me where the URL should be taken from when the template is expanded? Is it supposed to be entered manually? if so, what's your problem?

Comment: feature request for making links clickable: [IDEA-64131](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64131)